# Can React and jQuery be used together?

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I am working on a react project. Our designer uses **jQuery** and **Bootstrap** for our web-app . Can I use both React and jQuery together? Are these compatible together?

Comment: yes, they are compatible

Comment: See [this article by the React team](https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html)

Answer (score 1):

Not for the same section of the page.

In general, react is a bit clingy and likes to keep the full ownership for the dom node. However, it doesn't has to be the root node, just A node.

Take this for example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!--- scripts, fonts and css--->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="react-root"></div>
    <div id="jquery-node"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In this, as long as your jquery doesn't try to modify the #react-root node, everything is peachy.

Note that you can pretty much do anything throughout the page, just do not modify or even assume anything about the #react-node or anything inside it.

Comment: There's a big caveat here -- you _can_ actually manipulate the DOM directly, with jQuery or even raw JavaScript. The key problem is that React keeps track of the state of a virtual DOM, and not that of the browser DOM itself. Since jQuery interacts with the DOM itself, React can't track any changes made by not-React. This can make stuff break!

Comment: Sure, and the VDOM is tied to the node that is bound to react. Nothing above that. You are free to do whatever you please as long as you don't touch the react-root node or anything underneath, as I already mentioned.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you _can_ touch anything underneath the mount point, though. I don't ever recommend doing it, but I have done this in a pinch.